# opennssl s_client shows wrong cert: browser shows correct

Tags: nginx

We have 2 domains pointing to the same public AWS ELB and behind that ELB we have nginx, which will redirect requests to the correct server.

When we hit sub.domainA.com in the Browser (Chrome/Safari/etc), everything works, but when we use tools like openssl, we get a cert error:

```
openssl s_client -host sub.domainA.com -port 443 -prexit -showcerts

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.domainB.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
```

For some reason, domainA is using domainB certs and I have no idea why.

I'm almost 100% sure the issue is with our nginx config (and more specifically, not having a default server block)

Here is our nginx config:

```
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
...
    #
    # DomainB
    #

    server {
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/domainB.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/domainB.key;

        listen 8080;

        server_name *.domainB.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  logstash_json;

        error_page 497 301 =200 https://$host$request_uri;

        set $target_web "web.domainB_internal.com:80";
        location / {
            keepalive_timeout  180;
            resolver 10.10.0.2 valid=30s;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://$target_web;
            proxy_set_header X-Unique-ID $request_id;
        }
    }

    #
    # DomainA
    #
    server {
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/domainA.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/domainA.key;


        listen 8080;
        server_name *.domainA.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  logstash_json;

        error_page 497 301 =200 https://$host$request_uri;

        set $target_web "web.domainA_internal.com:80";

        location / {
            keepalive_timeout  180;
            resolver 10.10.0.2 valid=30s;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://$target_web;
            proxy_set_header X-Unique-ID $request_id;
        }
    }
}
```

It shouldn't even be falling in the domainB block at all!
Yet we see it when using "openssl s_client", but not in the browser.

Any ideas why we see domainB at all when using "openssl s_client -host sub.domainA.com"?

Very similar to [Openssl shows a different server certificate while browser shows correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420694/openssl-shows-a-different-server-certificate-while-browser-shows-correctly)

Very helpful website: https://tech.mendix.com/linux/2014/10/29/nginx-certs-sni/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the `servername` option in your `openssl` command.

From the [openssl s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html) docs:

> -servername name
>
> Set the TLS SNI (Server Name Indication) extension in the ClientHello
>   message.

So try something like

```
openssl s_client -connect sub.domainA.com:443 -showcerts -servername sub.domainA.com
```

Comment: The issue is on nginx, not the tool that is hitting the https endpoint.  For instance, it fails on openssl s_client, some browsers that don't forward servername, some services like newrelic that try to hit the endpoint, etc, etc.   I can run openssl s_client with servname, but what about everything else?

Comment: If the client does not specify the SNI name as part of the SSL handshake, how is nginx supposed to know which certificate to present? It is the client's job to specify which host it wants to connect to in the SSL handshake itself because the host header is sent much later as part of the HTTP request.

Comment: Good question, @Rahul ! This is my guess: since openssl s_client works for one domain and not the other (ie fails: "openssl s_client -host sub.domainA.com -port 443 -prexit -showcerts" works: "openssl s_client -host sub.domainB.com -port 443 -prexit -showcerts", I'm guessing that nginx is using the certs defined in the FIRST server block (which is domainB) in the configuration.  I'm still learning nginx, but shouldn't nginx know that server block to use based on the request? I can't wait to figure this out!

Comment: Of course nginx will present the first certificate since it does not know which one to present during the handshake which happens *before* the HTTP request is sent. That is why the concept of TLS SNI exists, so that the client is able to specify which domain it wants to connect to during the SSL handshake. In fact, specifying different hosts in the TLS SNI and HTTP request headers is a form of attack which you can read about http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134021/what-kind-of-attack-is-prevented-by-apache2s-error-code-ah02032-hostname-prov/

Comment: ah ha! that helped a lot. I read that link and it makes sense. My nginx router scored a "B" on ssllabs.com and another one of my domains got an "F"!  Thank you for responding to this. servername did the trick.